# Google Maps custom label x and y position

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to adjust the x and y position of my custom label. Is this possible?
I haven't come across any documentation regarding this issue as of yet.

```js
numberMarkerImg = {
    url: '../images/mobile/map-marker.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(32, 38),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 38)
};

// Letter markers
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : point,
    map      : map,
    icon     : numberMarkerImg,
    draggable: false,
    labelClass: "labels",
    label: {
        text: saved_label,
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: '12px',
        x: '200',
        y: '100'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

"labelOrigin" ended up having to to be passed in since I am using a custom marker.

```
   numberMarkerImg = {
        url: '../images/mobile/map-marker.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(32, 38),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 38),
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(9, 9)
   };
```

Answer (score 8):

Google Maps API v3 doesn't let you set [`MarkerLabel` position](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerLabel), there're no `x` and `y` options.

The doc also says:

> If you are using it with a custom marker, you can reposition it with the labelOrigin property in the Icon class.

As I can see you're using custom marker so maybe this is the way to go for you.

Alternatively, have a look at [MarkerWithLabel](https://github.com/jesstelford/node-MarkerWithLabel). Is an extension to the default `Marker` object with more options available. Small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LLd4drvx/239/.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I ended up using "labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(9, 9)"

Answer (score 8):

Another option I don't see mentioned here. You can set a CSS class for the label, then set the position using CSS. First, add className to the label:

```
label: {
    text: saved_label,
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: '12px',
    className: 'marker-position',
}
```

And for the CSS:

```
.marker-position {
    bottom: 6px;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I need. Thank Will!

Answer (score 3):

For v3, you can use it like this. The blue pointer shown in the picture is an icon I use as svg. with the appropriate label position for this icon.

```js
  iconSVG = {
    path: `M13.04,41.77c-0.11-1.29-0.35-3.2-0.99-5.42c-0.91-3.17-4.74-9.54-5.49-10.79c-3.64-6.1-5.46-9.21-5.45-12.07
        c0.03-4.57,2.77-7.72,3.21-8.22c0.52-0.58,4.12-4.47,9.8-4.17c4.73,0.24,7.67,3.23,8.45,4.07c0.47,0.51,3.22,3.61,3.31,8.11
        c0.06,3.01-1.89,6.26-5.78,12.77c-0.18,0.3-4.15,6.95-5.1,10.26c-0.64,2.24-0.89,4.17-1,5.48C13.68,41.78,13.36,41.78,13.04,41.77z
        `,
    fillColor: '#0084ff',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeColor: '#ffffff',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(14, 43),
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(13.5, 15)
  };
```

This sequence is a faster way to find the right position. **size**, **anchor**, **labelOrigin**

[image]